# Not possible to install tensorflow 1.3.0

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to get the `Mask R CNN to work from this Github repo: [Mask_RCNN](https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN)

This requires `TensorFlow 1.3.0` but when I try to install this specific version it just installs `TensorFlow 2.0.0` anyway. I am using the following command:

```
pip install tensorflow>=1.3.0
```

I am also using python 3.7.1

Comment: Have you actually experienced that it does *not* work with 2.0.0? Their [`requirements.txt`](https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN/blob/master/requirements.txt) says `tensorflow>=1.3.0`. (Btw. you could install the whole "file" as `pip install -r requirements.txt`)

Comment: I think Tensorflow 2.0.0 is not backwards compatible. Thats why I wanted to install 1.3.0. However, I found out that there is a compatibility package available so importing tensorflow.compat.v1 made everything work.

Comment: Ah, I was going to suggest opening an issue, but apparently someone created one just a week ago: https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN/issues/1835

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are downloading the latest tensorflow version, but greater than `1.3.0` with `>=1.3.0`

What you need is:

```
pip install tensorflow==1.13.1
```

Comment: It is not working for me. It gives me the error: "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.3.0 (from versions: 1.13.0rc1, 1.13.0rc2, 1.13.1, 1.13.2, 1.14.0rc0, 1.14.0rc1, 1.14.0, 2.0.0a0, 2.0.0b0, 2.0.0b1) No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.3.0"

Comment: @RodrigoVimieiro Updated